# Use if else statement for Dummy-Coding in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I tried to create a If Else Statement to Recode my Variable in a Dummy-Variable.

I Know there is the ifelse() Function and the fastDummy-Package, but I tried this Way without succes.

Why does this not work? I want to learn and understand R in a better Way.

```
if(df$iscd115==1){
  df$iscd1151 <- 1
} else {
  df$iscd1151 <- 0
}
```

Comment: `if` isn't vectorized - it checks a single boolean- looks for a single TRUE or FALSE, and acts accordingly. `ifelse` is vectorized, it checks a vector of booleans. If you have more than one row in your data frame, then `df$iscd115 == 1` gives multiple TRUE of FALSE values, one for each row, but since `if()` isn't vectorized it looks only at the first one (and warns you accordingly with *"the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"*). You could write a `for` loop and use `if` on each individual row, but that would be more work for both you and for R.

Comment: `+(df$iscd115 == 1)` will give you `1`s and `0`s (without `if` and `ifelse`), though it's just a shortcut assuming logicals coerced into integers. As GregorThomas said, `ifelse` is the more canonical method if you want anything much more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a reasonable solution.

First we'll find out what the positions of your important columns are, and then we'll `apply` a function that will search the rows (margin = 1)  that will check if that our important column is 1 or 0, and then modify the other column accordingly.

```
col1 <- which(names(df) == "iscd115")
col2 <- which(names(df) == "iscd1151")

mat <- apply(df, margin = 1, function(x) {
    if (x[col1] == 1) {x[col2] <- 1
    } else {
    x[col2] == 0
    }
    x
    })
```

Unfortunately, this transforms the original data frame into a transposed matrix. We can re-transpose the matrix back and turn it back into a data frame with the following.

```
new_df <- as.data.frame( t(mat))
```